# How to properly format directory tree in Confluence?

Tags: formatting, markup, confluence

I want to properly format the directory tree diagram, like:

```
   - /folder1 
          - /folder2
          - /folder3
               - file1
               - file2
```

What markup should I use for this purpose?

Answer (score 8):

I know I am digging up the subject, but I had the same question while writing documentation, and none of the proposed solutions suited me (like the author it seems). So for future reference, here another solution

Using only ascii characters to form the tree structure (│, ├, ─, └), and Shift + Enter between lines to reduce line spacing. It's quite visual

[image: Ascii tree representation]

```
├─ folder1
│   ├─ subFolder1
│   ├─ subFolder2
│   ├─ subFolder3
│   └─ subFolder4
└─ folder2
```

Answer (score 5):

If you have access to the Linux `tree` command you can do `tree -Q --charset=ascii`. (you can use cygwin under Windows)  This is not the same as MTD's answer because you have to account for the output characters and quoting the filenames with spaces.  If you don't use `--charset=ascii` you will get characters that Confluence can't handle.

```
tree -Q --charset=ascii
.
`-- "Folder 1"
    |-- "Folder 2"
    `-- "Folder 3"
        |-- "File 1"
        `-- "File 2"

3 directories, 2 files
```

Then place it in a code block on Confluence

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Are you looking for something like below snapshot? If so, then this is how you can achieve this.

- Type - (dash)and press space to create a bullet.
- Press tab to create a child bullet point.
- Press enter to add multiple bullet points and so on.

You can use toolbar icons to do the above formatting but it's easy for me to use keyboard hence provided you this approach.

[image]
You can learn more about text formatting in Confluence from Atlassian's documentation:

- https://confluence.atlassian.com/doc/confluence-wiki-markup-251003035.html#ConfluenceWikiMarkup-Lists

Thank you!

Comment: That's really nice, but is not exactly what I am looking for. Anyway thank you for your efforts!

Comment: Let me know what exactly are you looking for in detail? I would try to improve my answer.

Answer (score 2):

I've just used the Code Block macro and inserted plain text as in your question, or the output of `tree -d .`